# How to get Key authors list from my references?

Tags: bibliographies, jabref, keywords

Currently I'm managing my thesis bibliography with [JabRef](http://www.jabref.org/) and I want to know how to obtain key authors list and relations between them from all these references. I know that this can be accomplished by using charts, citation reports and graphs provided by ISI Web of knowledge. But I wanted to know if there is another way to do it.

Comment: What relationship with (La)TeX?

Comment: [JabRef](http://www.jabref.org/) is possibly the most prominent bibliographic manager for bibtex databases. There are currently 121 [questions tagged with jabref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jabref). There are also tags for other bibliography management software such as [BibDesk](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bibdesk).

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this is not possible.

Recommender systems are planned in this year (2016): http://www.docear.org/docear/blog/. So, if you know an IT master student, feel free to recommend a project in Japan.

Charting is discussed among the developers: https://github.com/koppor/jabref/issues/38. There is also the [PRRV plugin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jabrefprrvp/), but it is implemented straight-forwardly, and the developers should come up with a better approach: https://github.com/koppor/jabref/issues/95.

Links between entries are discussed among the JabRef developers: https://github.com/koppor/jabref/issues/14. Also cross-references: https://github.com/koppor/jabref/issues/79.